# Concordância de "Finanças" em bordão ou expressão

Tags: gramática, concordância-verbal, concordância-nominal

Num contexto de expressão ou bordão publicitário, está correto dizer "Finanças é coisa séria", tomando 'finanças' como um assunto específico, ou eu deveria concordar o verbo 'ser' e o predicativo 'coisa séria'?
"Finanças são coisas sérias" não soa tão impactante dum ponto de vista publicitário.

"Finança é coisa séria" me soa errado, pois eu sempre vejo e ouço 'finanças'.

Podemos, devemos, usar a palavra grafada no plural para indicar uma única prática ou doutrina?

Agradeço de antemão.

Comment: Disculpa mas me parece que "é coisa séria" virou expressão idiomática. e bem popular. Então é invariável mas soa um pouquinho boteco da esquina. Depende do nível de língua que você está procurando usar.

Comment: A expressão é usada no nosso _website_, cujo público alvo é a população geral da cidade. Somos uma cidade de cerca de 22.000 habitantes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está incorreto.

De fato, em geral o verbo tende a estar no plural quando um dos termos (sujeito ou predicado) está no plural, como em "A pátria são todos.", mas há exceções.
Especialmente quando o termo no plural é entendido em sua totalidade, como uma entidade única, é possível se ter o verbo no singular.

Isso é bem explicado na postagem [A concordância do verbo ‘ser’ são muitas](https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/a-concordancia-do-verbo-ser-sao-muitas/):

> no seguinte exemplo de Carlos Drummond de Andrade: “Oito anos sempre é alguma coisa”. Ou numa construção como “Cem reais é um preço justo”. Na formulação dos gramáticos Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra, isso se dá “quando o sujeito é constituído de uma expressão numérica que se considera em sua totalidade”. Ou seja: ao falar em oito anos, Drummond não se refere a cada um deles, mas a um período completo com essa duração. O mesmo raciocínio vale para os cem reais. Em outras palavras, o verbo no singular se explica pela ideia de um termo subentendido (período, quantia).

[Também termos](http://educacao.globo.com/portugues/assunto/usos-da-lingua/concordancia-verbal-e-nominal.html) como "muito", "pouco", "nada", "mais de", "tanto", "bastante", etc. podem reduzir o termo no plural a uma medida:

> Dez reais é quase nada.
> Dez anos é muito.

E também palavras como "coisa" e "assunto" [podem permitir](https://www.migalhas.com.br/coluna/gramatigalhas/325676/e-ou-sao) o singular:

> a) "Os responsórios e os sinos **é** coisa importuna em Tibães" (Camilo Castelo Branco);
> b) "Vestidos e modas **é** assunto para mulheres" (Domingos Paschoal Cegalla).

E imagino que, no exemplo específico da pergunta, também ajuda a permitir o singular o fato da palavra "finanças", apesar de quase sempre usada no plural (cerca de 100 vezes mais frequente que "finança" no [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/)), [ter significados](https://www.aulete.com.br/finan%C3%A7as) no singular: "situação/administração/sistema/órgão/ciência financeira".

Comment: Stafusa, boa resposta, mas acho que se fosse mais sucinta seria melhor.

Comment: @Schilive Penso que ela então contribuiria muito pouco além da resposta do Centaurus.

Comment: Aprecio ambas. Muito obrigado

Comment: Sim, não está errado, mas acho que a análise poderia falar de outras coisas como nível de língua etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128333/discussion-on-answer-by-stafusa-concordancia-de-financas-em-bordao-ou-expressa).

Answer (score 4):

Nada de errado a meu ver, se considerarmos "finanças" como um todo, e ***coisa*** como sinônimo de ***assunto.***  Eu vejo um artigo indefinido oculto em sua frase: **"finanças é um assunto sério."**

- "Finanças é uma das matérias mais interessantes no currículo deste semestre." Acho que ningém diria "finanças são uma das matérias..."  Mesmo sem o artigo indefinido, o verbo continuaria no singular - "finanças é a matéria mais interessante..."

Comment: Era disso que eu desconfiava! +1

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado

Comment: Em português o uso do artigo indefinido é imprescindível aqui. Ninguém fala em num assunto geral usando o plural assim em linguagem popular. "Droga é problema, meu filho". [com o sentido de: as drogas.} Sem s. Se usar o plural precisaria ser: As finanças são um assunto sério.

Answer (score -1):

Vejamos bem essa história.

Vejo este comentário: "Finança é coisa séria" me soa errado, pois eu sempre vejo e ouço 'finanças'." e sou lingüísta, o que diria?

1. *ser coisa séria* é uma expressão idiomática e popular.
2. Quando se fala num tema ou assunto, se usa o substantivo com o artigo definido.

- **A música** popular brasileira da década de 1960 é um assunto complicado.

Então, para ser formal, séria: A finança não é algo fácil de entender.

3. Se quiser usar um **registro popular**, se diria:
   **Finança é coisa séria.**
   como por exemplo, um pai diria a um filho:
   **"Droga não é brincadeira"**.
4. Se quiser um registro mais formal, se poderia dizer:
   **A finança é um assunto sério.** [a matéria ou ciência de administrar dinheiro]
5. O plural: As finanças da minha avó precisam ser revisadas.

Para mim, acho que a concordância do verbo ser não faria parte da minha análise neste caso.

Comment: Penso que o ponto 2 é incompleto: o exemplo de fato pede o artigo definido, mas especialmente por ser um tipo específico de música - creio que também é correto: "Música é meu passatempo predileto.". E, como você mesmo aponta, "finança", no singular, é muito menos usado e soa estranho, então eu não recomendaria o 3 ou o 4.

Comment: @stafusa Acho que não: "A música é um assunto com me interessa bastante". "A música é o meu passstempo predileto". Sem o artigo é popular:, é isso que estou dizendo. Agora, já consegui dois dv's.  Não colocar o artigo também se ve em títulos nos jornais. Estilo telegráfico. O exemplo que dei de finança sem o artigo é um registro popular. Já disse tudo que tinha que dizer. :)

Comment: Aparentemente, a galera não se interessa à redação ou a escritura. Falta de nível.

Comment: @Lambie, acho uma resposta interessante, mas, me intrometendo onde não sou chamado, fiquei curioso com algo, poderias explicar melhor de *música é o meu passamento predileto* ser popular?

Comment: @Schilive A falta de artigo indefinido é informal (ou pode tambem ser um título). Qualquer redação ou fala mais formal dirá: A música popular brasileira etc. A música é algo que me interessa. Geralmente, se começa com **o artigo indefinido**: A história do Brasil é complicada. Quando se diz, por exemplo. "história do Brasil é assunto complicado" numa conversa, está ok mas é informal ou popular. Numa conferência fulano diriá: **A história**, **A música**, **A finança**.

Comment: Como você me parece uma pessoa aberta, vou lhe comunicar outra ideia. Tenho problemas em quase todos os fóruns nessa praga [:)] porque como lingüista faço uma diferença nítida entre língua falada e língua escrita. Essa característica da linguagem é muitas vezes desconhecido pela galera geral. Então me vejo repetindo explicações duas ou tres vezes, mesmo quando o que escrevo é bem fácil. Sim, algo pode ser gramatical mas tambem pode ser algo que não se diría ou que geralmente não se ouve. :) Como se fala no verdadeiro mundo?

Comment: @Lambie, realmente, "história do Brasil é um assunto complicado" soa como se pessoa tivesse omitido o artigo, e escrito me semelha errado. A situação em que não me semelha errado é com substantivo que não leva artigo, como *história* como matéria: *história é legal, mas geografia é melhor*.

Comment: @Lambie, do teu segundo comentário, o Quora tem um grande problema com isso, pois, muitos lá se esquecem dessa diferença e amiúde a tratam como imposição artificial e irreal, conquanto ela exista há milênios e em línguas várias de culturas diversas! Ademais, o povo lá torna suposição própria em fato veríssimo! Eu me lembro dum cara que disse que *vamo'* não se pode considerar de nenhuma guisa errado, dando por argumento que, no italiano, um certo grupo considerava errado a omissão do -s nas conjugações da primeira pessoa do plural, mas depois outrossim começaram a omitir os -s, e hoje é regra.

Comment: @Schilive Dois professores universitários sentados num boteco tomando birita. Já ficarão bastante bêbados. Um fala pro outro: "Cara, história do Brasil é um assunto complicado." Tudo depende do **nível da fala e do registro**.  Já expliquei tudo isso na minha resposta. Leia quem queira.  A Quora se dane. :) Ciaozinho.